# Ошибка при компиляции TASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

```
MOV byte ptr DS:[BX + SI], ES:[SI]
```

В этой строчке TASM выдаёт ошибку:

> Illegal memory reference

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощь пересылки через регистр

```
MOV DL, DS:[BX + SI]  
MOV ES:[SI], DL
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет команд типа память-память. Решение использовать регистр верное.

Comment: Есть команды память-память (movs например), но явно указать два операнда, ссылающихся на память, нельзя.

Comment: И я не знаю ассемблеров, в которых можно было бы такое провернуть. Ответ лучше, чем самоответ топикстартера -- потому что объясняет механику. Я бы рекомендовал именно сюда поставить галку.